# I have problem with making AsynchTask for concrete Query in DAO

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, dao

In my dao Query:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = :rb")
    Object getObjectByID(int rb);
```

How to make appropriete asynch task in repository for this query?

Comment: dose you use room and live data ? if so you don't need AsyncTask for fetching data from room its already async.

Answer (score 0):

@Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = :rb")
LiveData getObjectByID(int rb);

no need of async task this will return livedata  always whenever data change on perticular id till observe

Comment: Thank you! This was very useful for me as beginner.